# Django Model with Oracle Database returns Error: ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: django, oracle, django-models

i try to connect two database tables with a foreign key and i get the error
`ORA-00904: "A"."A_NR_ID": invalid identifier`
for the model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    a_nr = models.ForeignKey(B, models.DO_NOTHING)
--> #anr = models.ForeignKey(B, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column="a_nr")
    f_b = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

If i replace **a_nr** with the comment-line **anr** it works. And i have no idea why, since the name only uses single underscore. Also the column f_b seems to work perfectly fine.
If i then run "makemigrations" it trys to delete the column **a_nr** and create **anr**, which also makes no sense to me, since i thought db_column="a_nr" would keep the actuall name in the oracle database the same.

The second error is:
 `ORA-00904: "D"."BEZEICHNUNG_ID": invalid identifier`
for the model:

```
class C(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bezeichnung = models.CharField()


class D(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bezeichnung =  models.ForeignKey(C, models.DO_NOTHING)
    ...
```

And here i can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It is the `, db_column="a_nr"` part, so `bezeichnung =  models.ForeignKey(C, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='bezeichnung')` should be used of the name of the database column is `bezeichnung`.

Comment: oh, that worked. I thought you only need `db_column` when the column name in django differs from the actual database.

Comment: for most model fields, that is indeed the case, for `ForeignKey`s, `OneToOneField`s, and some other (by some external Django apps), it will use by default a different column name (or multiple columns for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I replace `a_nr` with the comment-line `anr` it works. And I have no idea why, since the name only uses single underscore.

This has *nothing* to do with the name of the field, but that of the database: for a `ForeignKey`, and `OneToOneField`, if your field is named *`fieldname`*, it will use as database column by default `fieldname_id`. You can use the [**`db_column=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) to specify the name of the column to use, so:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_nr = models.ForeignKey(B, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='a_nr')
    # …


class D(models.Model):
    bezeichnung = models.ForeignKey(C, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='bezeichnung')
    # …
```